# Truth Tables with brackets in formula

Tags: logic

I am having trouble understanding how I approach truth tables when the expression is bracketed. The expression I am trying to put into a truth table is this:

A1 ∨ (A2 ∧ (A2 → A3))

Would I attack the most nestled set of brackets first and then move outwards, or go outward to in?

Answer (score 1):

You should start from the inner-most bracketed expression and work your way out.

Answer (score 1):

From the inside out.

How would you do a truth table for $A_1 \lor (A_2 \land (A_2 \rightarrow A_3))$ if you don't yet have the truth values for $(A_2 \land (A_2 \rightarrow A_3)$?